# Add buttons to html template, after receiving JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I want to add buttons to the DOM dynamically, after receiving JSON from my API when users access the site. I already implemented the function to get the data, but now I have problems to add the buttons dynamically to the HTML template. Furthermore, I don't know how to call a function on a first page load for a specific template.

Here is my code:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $http, ApiService) {
    $http.get('connection.properties').then(function (response) {
        ApiService.getAllElements($rootScope);
    });
});
```

In my ApiService I have this function:

```
        getAllElements : function($scope) {
            var requestData = {
                'username' : 'user123'
            };

            this.doRequest(requestData).success(function(data) {
               if (data.success) {
                    console.log(data); // add buttons
               }
            }).error(function() {
                alert('Sorry bro.');
            });
        }
```

I am a complete AngularJS beginner, so I don't know the correct way on how to do this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

data JSON structure looks like this:

```
{"success":true,"msg":"user active,1 element in db","userid":"1","elements":[{"element_id":"1","name":"Element1","description":"This is element 1"}]}
```

And in my profile.html template I have this static button:

```
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-elements">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="element" ng-change="save(true)" btn-radio="'1'">Element1</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: We need to know what the data looks like and what the buttons do to help you with this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you have multiple "elements" in those data ?
In that case, ng-repeat is great :

initialize your elements : (in controller)

```
$scope.elements = [];
```

link the template to the $scope thanks to angularjs native directives :

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-elements">
    <button ng-repeat="element in elements" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="doSomething( element, $index )">{{ element.name }}</button>
</div>
```

fetch the data :

```
    getAllElements : function($scope) {
        var requestData = {
            'username' : 'user123'
        };

        this.doRequest(requestData).success(function(data) {
           if (data.success) {
                $scope.elements = data.elements; // add buttons
           }
        }).error(function() {
            alert('Sorry bro.');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now I can see the button, but when I click on it and print `$scope.element` in my `save` function, there is not the value from `btn-radio`. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I used this to set it manually: `$scope.element = this.element;` but is this the correct way? I thought `$scope.element` should be automatically updated.

Comment: What is your objective ? I don't understand what you are trying to achieve so I can't help you more !

Comment: I edited the template : maybe what you want to do is add behavior to clicking the button ? In that case you can access the element in the arguments of the function, as well as the $index for example

Comment: My objective is to store the value from `btn-radio` in `$scope.element` when clicking the button and then access it from the function `save`. I thought `$scope.element` is set automatically thanks to `ng-model`, but this was not the case.